# Proving that the function is psd

Tags: self-study

To show for which values of $c\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $K_c(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}) := c+\sum^n_{i=1}x_iz_i$ is a psd, we need to show that the following inequality:

$$\sum_{i,j}a_ia_jK_c(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)\geq 0$$

For all $a_i\in\mathbb{R}, i\in\{1,...,m\}$ and for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

We have that $$\sum_{i,j}a_ia_jK_c(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)\geq 0 \\  \sum_{i,j}a_ia_j\left(c+\sum_{k=1}^nx_{ik}x_{jk}\right)\geq 0 \\ c\sum_{i,j}a_ia_j+\sum_{i,j}a_ia_j\sum_kx_{ik}x_{jk}\geq 0 \\ c\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2+\sum_k\left(\sum_ia_ix_{ik}\right)\left(\sum_ja_jx_{jk}\right)\geq 0 \\ c\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2 + \langle\sum_ia_i\mathbf{x}_i,\sum_ja_j\mathbf{x}_j \rangle \geq 0 \\ c\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2 + \| \sum_ia_i\mathbf{x}_i\|^2\geq 0 \\ c\geq -\frac{\|\sum_ia_i\mathbf{x}_i\|^2}{\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2}$$

Since $\|\sum_ia_i\mathbf{x}_i\|^2\geq 0$ and assuming $\left(\sum_ia_i\right)\neq 0$ then $\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2\geq 0$, then the RHS can at most be $0$, hence for $c\geq 0$, $K_c(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$ is a psd.

Is this okay? Is it correct to make an assumption that $\left(\sum_ia_i\right)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m a_ia_jK_c(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j) 
= c \left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2  + \Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert^2 \geq 0 \\ \text{$\forall a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^m, i\in\{1,...,m\}$}
$$

- The right term $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert ^2$ is always non-negative
- The left term $\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2$ is also always non-negative

Consider the following four situations

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
& \left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2 = 0 & \left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2 > 0\\ 
\hline
\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert^2 = 0 & \text{$c$ can have any value} & c \geq 0 \\ 
\hline \\
\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert^2 > 0 & \text{$c$ can have any value} & c \geq \frac{\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2 }\\
\end{array}$$

In determining the possible values for $c$ the critical situation is not when $\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2 = 0$ but when $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i\mathbf{x}_i \Vert ^2 = 0$ while $\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \right)^2 > 0$.

Since this may happen (e.g. $x_1 = - x_2$ and $a_1 = a_2$) we must have $c \geq 0$

Comment: +1 -- but I believe that everywhere you write $||\quad ||$ you really intend $||\quad||^2.$